# ${port} doesn't highlight as a variable

Tags: express

```
import express from "express"
import mongoose from "mongoose"

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8001;

app.get("/", (req, res) => res.status(200).send("Hello World"));

app.listen(port, () => console.log("${port}"));
```

`console.log` only gives `${port}` and not `8001`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) use backticks:

```
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`${port}`));
```

(Though, `console.log(port);` should also be fine here)

Answer (score 2):

Use **backticks** instead of **strings**. It's called **Template Literals** in JS. For more details, you can visit JS documentation.

```
console.log(`${port}`)
```

Since you only use a variable, you don't need to put it into the string. You can also write it something like that:

```
console.log(port)
```

So the whole code will be:

```
import express from "express"
import mongoose from "mongoose"

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8001;

app.get("/", (req, res) => res.status(200).send("Hello World"));

app.listen(port, () => console.log(port));
```